# "Save a custom chart as a template" button / shortcut / quick access bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, shortcuts, ribbon

In the OFFICE newer versions (+2010), the button **Save as Template** in the **Design tab**/**Type** group vanishes. I know it can be reached by right-clicking the chart, and cliking **Save as Template**. But I would like to put it inside the **Design tab** as it was the case in Word 2007/2010 (cf. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/save-a-custom-chart-as-a-template-259a5f9d-a9ec-4b3f-94b6-9f5e55187f2a). I was looking inside the Word options and try to customize the ribbon (cf. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-word-c4b6051a-7a70-43c8-a527-932917dec682), but I didn't find the command Save as Template in all the commands. Where is it going?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, the command "Save as Template" has been removed from Word ribbon since Office 2013. In addition, the command can't be found in the command list in Customize Ribbon window.

For the requirement, I suggest you send your feedback in [Word UserVoice](https://word.uservoice.com/) forum.

Comment: Huuuum... ok thank you